# Utilizing Firefox's default/built-in Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I have a context menuitem which is activated if an image is right-clicked, the exact same way that `'context-copyimage'` is activated.

Is it possible to tie/pair that menuitem to the `'context-copyimage'` therefore eliminating the need to add extra (duplicate) event-listeners and show/hide handlers??!!
(Adding an observer to `'context-copyimage'` defeats the purpose)

If not, is it possible to use the event-listener that `'context-copyimage'` uses?

Update:
I am trying to reduce listeners. At the moment, script has a `popupshowing` listeners. On `popupshowing`, it checks for `gContextMenu.onImag` and if true, it shows the menuitem. Firefox's `context-copyimage` does the exact same thing. I was wondering if it was possible to tie these 2 in order to remove/reduce the in-script event listeners.

I was also chatting with Dagger and he said that:

> ... the state of built-in items isn't set from an event handler, it's
>   set from the constructor for nsContextMenu, and there are no
>   mechanisms to hook into it

So it seems, that is not possible

Comment: Err... What? Could you be more specific, in particular to what event listeners you're referring to and what is the actual goal here?

Comment: Sure.... I will add more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no *sane* way of avoiding the event listener that would perform better than another event listener and is compatible with unloading the add-on in session.

#### Hooking `nsContextMenu`

As you have been already told, the state is initialized via `gContextMenu = new nsContextMenu(...)`. So you'd need to hook the stuff, which is actually quite easy.

```
var newProto = Object.create(nsContextMenu.prototype);
newProto.initMenuOriginal = nsContextMenu.prototype.initMenu;
newProto.initMenu = function() {
    let rv = this.initMenuOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("ctx", this.onImage, this); // Or whatever code you'd like to run.
    return rv;
};
nsContextMenu.prototype = newProto;
```

Now, the first question is: Does it actually perform better? After all this just introduced another link in the prototype-chain. Of course, one could avoid `Object.create` and just override `nsContextMenu.prototype.initMenu` directly.

But the real question is: How would one remove the hook again? Answer: you really cannot, as other add-ons might have hooked the same thing after you and unhooking would also unhook the other add-ons. But you need to get rid of the reference, or else the add-on will leak memory when disabled/uninstalled. Well, you could fight with [`Components.utils.makeObjectPropsNormal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.makeObjectPropsNormal), but that doesn't really help with closed-over variables. So lets avoid closures... Hmm... You'd need some kind of messaging, e.g. event listeners or observers... and we're back to square one.

Also I wouldn't call this *sane* compared to

```
document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu").addEventListener(...)
```

I'd call it "overkill for no measurable benefit".

#### Overriding `onpopupshowing=`

One could override the `<menupopup onpopupshowing=`. Yeah, that might fly... Except that other add-ons might have the same idea, so welcome to compatibility hell. Also this again involves pushing stuff into the window, which causes cross-compartment wrappers, which makes things error-prone again.

Is this a solution? Maybe, but not a **sane** one.

#### What else?

Not much, really.

Comment: Tnx Nils. Again,. I was exploring other possibilities which as you have mentioned, not a better option :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is absolutely possible.
Morat from mozillazine gave a great solution here: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=13307339&sid=0700480c573017c00f6e99b74854b0b2#p13307339

```
function handleClick(event) {
  window.removeEventListener("click", handleClick, true);
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var node = document.popupNode;
  document.popupNode = event.originalTarget;
  var menuPopup = document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu");
  var shiftKey = false;
  gContextMenu = new nsContextMenu(menuPopup, shiftKey);
  if (gContextMenu.onImage) {
    var imgurl = gContextMenu.mediaURL || gContextMenu.imageURL;
  }
  else if (gContextMenu.hasBGImage && !gContextMenu.isTextSelected) {
    var imgurl = gContextMenu.bgImageURL;
  }
  console.log('imgurl = ', imgurl)
  document.popupNode = node;
  gContextMenu = null;
}
window.addEventListener("click", handleClick, true);
```

this gives you access to `gContextMenu` which has all kinds of properties like if you are over a link, or if you right click on an image, and if you did than `gContextMenu.imageURL` holds its value. cool stuff

This code here console logs `imgurl`, if you are not over an image it will log `undefined`

Comment: This seems to be entirely unrelated to the question at hand... It shows how you can initialize and use `gContextMenu` outside of `popup*` events, e.g. on a regular click.